# list loaded apache2 modules fail in debian

Tags: apache2, debian

I wanna list loaded apache2 modules in debian 5, using

"**apache2 -M**"

but i have found it return following error

```
apache2: bad user name ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
```

any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with you environment variables, make sure they are right for apache2 utilities.
Have a try with "source /etc/apache2/envvars", which is supposed to fix your problem. 
Hope this help you.

Comment: The main idea is to make sure APACHE_RUN_USER and APACHE_RUN_GROUP have been defined, which should be found in envvars. If not, just run"export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data" yourself.